# Método que conte os frames de uma cena de Realidade Aumentada em C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou fazendo um trabalho de Realidade Aumentada utilizando Unity e Vuforia e preciso capturar quantos frames a cena que eu desenvolvo está utilizando, não domino muito de C#, mas pelas minhas pesquisas aparentemente o unity não possui nenhum método getFrame() como o ARToolKit disponibiliza, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Quando você diz que precisa capturar quantos frames a cena está utilizando, você esta querendo saber o total de frames acumulado na execução completa da cena, ou quantos frames são produzidos por segundo?
Bem, em ambos os casos o caminho é o mesmo, na função `Update()`, ela é chamada a cada novo frame criado, e só mudar a implementação de acordo com o que você quer.
exemplo `fps = 1.0/Time.deltaTime;`
https://youtu.be/0rD4OuPxsuk?t=10m19s

Comment: @Nils, cria uma resposta com esse conteúdo. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de encontrar estes valores no Unity está na utilização do método `Update()` , ele é interno da ferramente e é chamado cada vez que um frame é criado.
Para saber o número total de frames que foram gerados, podemos criar uma variável e acrescentar 1 a cada chamada do método.

```
int frame; //total de frames criados

Update(){
  frame++;
}
```

E para saber o `fps` podemos pegar o inverso da variação de tempo entre cada chamada

```
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float fps = 0.0f;

void Update()
{
    deltaTime += (Time.deltaTime - deltaTime) * 0.1f;
    fps = 1.0f / deltaTime;
}
```

Você pode usar estes valores das variáveis e trabalhar como quiser.

> Sobre a função Update https://youtu.be/0rD4OuPxsuk?t=10m19s
>
> Algumas implementações de FPS no Unity: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=FramesPerSecond